# how do I use partials in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Today we started our Laravel 5 lessons in school. So I started to search the web to re-use things. I've read some things about sections, components and yielding but I still don't quite understand it.

In my `resources/views` folder I have a file called `home.blade.php`. 
It contains this navigation bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/control-panel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

now in my `about.blade.php` I'd like to use the same code without copy and pasting. So if I made a change it would change both navigation bars instantly without changing it 2 times.

Can someone explain to me how I re-use this navigation bar without copy and pasting?

Thanks in advance, Sylent.

Comment: You need to show us some code. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That's the whole problem, I'm looking for a way to re-use the navigation bar without copy pasting it the whole time. But I actually have 0 Laravel knowledge so everything I tried doesn't work

Comment: Short answer: Put the navigation into its own blade file. Include that navigation with `@yield`

Comment: Here is the documentation, where you can find all of your answers: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade

Comment: Please update the question title. "things" should be named "partials" (or at least "html")

Comment: @winkbrace updated, I didn't know how it was called.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a new folder and call it partials. There you could have navigation, header and footer all as separate blade files.

You would then (usually) create a layout blade that contains the structure and includes the navigation, header and footer.

You would then extend that layout for home and about, and encapsulate whatever content for each of home and about by creating a section called content.

You would then yield content within the layout.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade

```
#navigation /resources/views/partials/navigation.blade.php
<nav>
...
</nav>

#header /resources/views/partials/header.blade.php
<header>
...
</header>


#footer /resources/views/partials/footer.blade.php
<footer>
...
</footer>

#layout /resources/views/layouts/layout.blade.php
@include('partials.header')

@include('partials.navigation')

    <div class="main-content">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

@include('partials.footer')

#home /resources/views/page/home.blade.php
@extends('theme.layouts.layout')

@section('content')
    <p>Anything within home</p>
@endsection

#about /resources/views/page/about.blade.php
@extends('theme.layouts.layout')

@section('content')
    <p>Anything within about</p>
@endsection
```

Comment: So I need to make a folder called `partials` and put my navigation bar in there. Then use `@yield('navbar)'` in my `home.blade.php`?

Comment: @Sylent I updated my post. Above shows the typical format, and how it would work.

Comment: Oh so that's how it works, I couldn't figure it out. I just tried it with just 1 partial and it worked. I greatly appreciate the help. This will make DRY a lot easier I guess

Comment: Thanks! Had been looking for this for ages, so simple when you lay it out as you have!